# Does Box.com AppToApp API supported on iPhone or only on iPad

Tags: box-api

As the subject says does Box.com AppToApp API supported on iPhone or only on iPad? And what about Android, is it supported on any Android device?

I'm asking because on Box site is says it's only supported on iPad but it does not make sense.

Thanks,
Vitali Fridman

Answer (score 0):

AppToApp is currently only supported on iPad.

AppToApp is also supported on Android, and the docs can be found here: http://developers.box.com/the-box-sdk-for-onecloud-on-android/